# Join 3 tables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables in which a role has a number of permission which resides in the `Roledetail` table I have to find out the `PermissionName, RoleId, RoleName, RoleDescription` from these tables:

```
[Role], Permission, RoleDetail
```

Table `[Role]` has these columns:

```
RoleID, RoleName, RoleDescription
```

and table `Permission` has these columns:

```
PemissionId, PermissionName
```

while table `RoleDetail` has these columns:

```
RoleDetailId, PermissionId, RoleID
```

I want to display the columns `RoleId, RoleName, RoleDescription, PermissionName` based on a given `permissionId` from the `RoleDetail` table
and here what i have so far

```
Alter PROCEDURE usp_GetRoleDetails
@proleId int    
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Select r.RoleId,r.RoleName,r.[Description],permissionName from 
[Role]r
Inner join RoleDetail d on  d.RoleDetailId = r.RoleID
Inner join Permission p on p.PermissionId =  d.PermissionId
where r.RoleId = @proleId


END
GO
```

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service: have you tried creating a `select` statement (that cab wrapped in a stored proc. later)?

Comment: Why don't just use `join`?

Comment: Because that would mean he would have to learn SQL and use energy of his own. Asking other people to do the basic work is a core competency of many developers these days, it seems.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Please show that you have a basic understanding of what you are doing and show us where you fail - and what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this

```
Select RoleId,RoleName,RoleDescription,permissionName from 
RoleDetail 
Inner join [Role] on RoleDetail.RoleDetailId = Role.RoleID
Inner join Permission on Permission.PemissionId =  RoleDetail.PemissionId
```

Comment: in roledetail table a roleid has multiple permissionsId and i have to find out all the permission name according to permissionid but its showing only one record.

Comment: sir wat i have tried so far is updated in my question nd have a look where i am doing wrong

Comment: Try this                                                                         `Select R.RoleId, R.RoleName,P.Permission from Role R inner join RoleDetail D on R.RoleId = D.RoleId Inner join Permission P on D.PermissionId = P.PermissionId where R.RoleId =@proleId`

Answer (score 1):

A simple SQL join would do the trick. SQL joins help fetch data from multiple tables as in your case.All you would need for the join is to have the tables  is for the tables to have a primary key - foreign key relationship, such as the PermissionId and RoleDetail columns in your case. But be very careful, joins can also give you duplicate records if the join's on clause is not proper. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for an introduction to SQL joins.

Comment: providing a link with no details is not a acceptable way to answer on the site. Please expand your answer with some relevant information from the link, adding quote text where appropriate and try to explain why it will help in some of your own words.

Comment: The developer clearly could have researched some more on the topic. Even a simple google search would have shown him that joins were the answer to his problem. My answer was therefore intended to get him learn from the site - a lazy answer for a lazy question. Sorry if I came on as being rude or unhelpful.

Comment: The issue is that links may change over time, but if you post some detail in your answer it will remain. please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers and improve or delete your answer, otherwise it's likely to get automatically flagged for being too short and once it's reviewed it'll get deleted for being a link-only answer.